# Folder permission

Tags: linux

Really new to Linux. I need give access to a folder (/my/sites/folders) to a domain user (atest). This is CentOS 7 and domain joined. Sadly I have spent too much time already and lack understanding of this basic command.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running `chown` ?

Something like `chown -R atest: /my/sites/folders`. Maybe you will need super user permissions to do that. I don't remember if CentOS have `sudo` but if it does you only need to put it before `chown`: `sudo chown...`. If not, login as root first.

More info at [chown man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chown) and [some examples](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/06/chown-examples).

You may also want to try adding the atest user to the www-data group (or whatever group apache runs as on centos). This will ensure the website itself can read and execute files in its folder.